# iPhone - Synchronize two iPhones to make them start task on same time

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to make an application that will start playing same media on two (or more) iPhones simultaneously, the problem is that it has to be perfect, no second delays and such. Is it possible that iPhone has some universal time stamp that is perfectly (or near-perfect) on every device. Or maybe I have some other options?

Comment: Are they going to be in close proximity to each other? Is there going to be a local network that they can all connect to?

Comment: They will be close, but have no idea about network..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no internal clock that is different to the system clock - so this means that each of the devices could have completely different time settings (in fact, it's highly likely that they will have different time settings even if only by a second or two).

Using a network/internet connection to synchronise against a central time server may be an approach that could be taken, but that would then require the network/internet connection and you would have to set the clocks taking into account lags on the connection to/from the time server.

You could have to have some kind of local synchronising system. If they are in close proximity, one approach may be to create an ad-hoc bluetooth connection between the devices in your app and then use some synchronisation code in you app to get the internal timers the same. You could, for example, have the first app to launch be the "controller" and then all the other apps would seek this controller and synchronise against it. The synchronisation could just be the controller sending out timestamp messages which the other devices can get and set an internal counter to match.

Without knowing much more about the requirements, it's hard to say how best to approach this as there may be limitations regarding time between running the app and it making the sound, or if you have to have a triggering signal, or if it is just at time x they need to make the sound.

Answer (score 1):

2 rules:

1. Find a way to have the same time on each devices
2. Use a "startAtTime" function using this shared uniform time. No "startNow" function.

the iPhones are supposed to be able to sync their date and time using a remote server, if this is not accurate enough (who knows), a way to achieve this (assuming you iPhone are able to communicate between them already):

- The master send its time to a slave 10 (or more) times.
- Each time the slave compare it's time with the one received and make a delta
- After 10 tries, make a mean of the deltas and use this mean to adjust the slave time accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If they are in same time zone and same time set ,you can schedule it to start your function in the paticular point of time using NSTimer's

`- (id)initWithFireDate:(NSDate *)date interval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)t selector:(SEL)s userInfo:(id)ui repeats:(BOOL)rep;`.

Comment: This will only work if the devices all have EXACTLY the same time set

Comment: but what if they both have different time set on the devices.. ? (automatic time update is turned off)

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to access the time from a common server and then start a timer on both devices accordingly (calculating depending on the time you got from the service)so you have exact time on both the devices and then play it ...

Even this has a catch as internet speed may vary and there might be a slight in delay on one of the two devices in getting the response from the server as compared to the other device and looking at your requirement they might go out of sync by a milisecond or so which will be visible.. :/ any other ideas anyone.. ?

Comment: I think if you're trying to precisely synchronize the clocks of 2 or more nearby devices and the network latency is unknown, the only way is to use an auditory ("tick!") or video (flash) cue. Either that or architect your solution to handle devices which may be up to 5 seconds off from each other.